# Manage free version and paid version in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the best way to manage free version and paid version using Flutter?

What I have checked

- One dirty way is having two almost identical projects, and building one as a free version and the other as a paid version.
- Another way is implementing differences between versions as features after in-app purchase. (I might go with this if there is no better way.)
- I found info for Android and for iOS (which are the ones written above), but does Flutter provide a better way?

**Environment**

- 1.12.13+hotfix.9
- Dart 2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Implement in-app-purchases with a non-consumable (if you want to
   unlock premium features 'forever')
2. Create a subscription that a user
   purchases to unlock premium features (potentially combined with
   a free trial period) for a period of time

Anything else is likely to get blocked by the App Store and Play Store review process.